# Are eigenvalues of elliptic PDE real when $u$ is real valued function and all coefficients are real?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I asked this to my professor and am more confused than before.

Let's say we have $(L-\lambda)u=0$. In order for $u$ to be nontrivial real valued function, shouldn't $\lambda$ necessarily be real value?

$Lu$ is real value and $u$ is real value so we necessarily have real $\lambda$...

This seems very obvious.. but probably I'm missing something - my professor said otherwise and didn't understand his answer. Please help..

Comment: Is $L$ elliptic by itself or is $L-\lambda I$ supposed to be elliptic?

Comment: I think $L$ is elliptic if and only if $L-\lambda I$ is elliptic right? Since (uniform) ellipticity is about second order term

Comment: I'm asking you. Is $L$ an elliptic operator in your setup? You talk about elliptic PDE in the title but don't actually say whether $L$ is elliptic in your question.

Comment: sorry yes!!  I should have said L is an elliptic operator

Comment: If $L$ is not symmetric, you can only guarantee that the principle eigenvalue is real, but not all of them. Take a look in Evans 6.5.2.

Comment: @Mr.Brown thanks! then do you think I got the definition of eigenvalue wrong?I don't see any contradiction on why $\lambda$ shouldn't be real

Comment: what do you mean by principle eigenvalue? do you mean just eigenvalue, not continuous/residual spectrum?

Comment: @Mr.Brown I believe there is actually a typo in the main theorem of this section in the 1st Edition. The the theorem actually states that all eigenvalues have real part less than the principle eigenvalue but they prove that the real parts are all alrger, which makes more sense

Comment: Ok it looks like that issue was fixed in the 2nd edition (which I have). Min Seok, it's as @whpoweell96 suggests, all other (complex) eigenvalues have real part greater than the principle eigenvalue. Maybe you can also consider the Rayleigh quotient.

Comment: I have an electronic copy so I will be sure to update mine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lambda$ isn't real in general because elliptic operators are not necessarily self-adjoint, e.g., $Lu = -u'' + u'$. Just like in the finite-dimensional case, one may need to extend the eigenvalues and eigenvectors(functions) to be complex-valued to ensure existence of solutions to the eigenproblem.

For example, the operator $L = -u'' + u'$ on $[0,\pi]$ with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions has eigenvalues $\lambda_k = k^2 +ik$ for $k=1,2,\dots$ with corresponding eigenfunctions $\phi_k(x) = e^{ikx}$. If you only consider real-valued functions, there are no eigenvalues or eigenfunctions. The extension to complex variables is not as drastic as it might seem, as it only really forces you to properly use complex conjugates in your inner products and use the complex modulus squared instead of just squaring, for instance.

As for what you can actually say about elliptic operators in general, Theorem 3 of Section 6.5.2 of Evans (as @Mr.Brown noted) guarantees that one eigenvalue of the operator $L$ is always real. This theorem guarantees that such an elliptic operator under mild assumptions

1. $L$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ called the *principle eigenvalue* such that $\lambda_1$ is real and for any other eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $L$, $$Re(\lambda) \geq \lambda_1.$$
2. The eigenfunction corresponding to $\lambda_1$ is positive everywhere in the domain
3. $\lambda_1$ is a simple eigenvalue.

Note: The example $L$ I gave actually does not satisfy the conditions for this theorem as it requires the addition of a term $cu$ where $c>0$.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I'm still unsure if in the case of real valued function we'll only have real eigenvalues. I'll definitely have a look on this section